# Unix time stamp conversion using pandas issue

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I have a pandas dataframe, `df` which looks like this:

```
       _sent_time_stamp  distance  duration  duration_in_traffic   Orig_lat  
0            1456732800      1670       208                  343  51.441092
```

I want to convert the epoch time value (_sent_time_stamp) into two columns, one with the date and one with the hour.

I define two functions:

```
def date_convert(time):
    return time.date()

def hour_convert(time):
    return time.hour()
```

I then use lambda calculus to apply these functions and create 2 new columns.

```
df['date'] = Goo_results.apply(lambda row: date_convert(pd.to_datetime(row['_sent_time_stamp'], unit='s')), axis=1)

df['hour'] = Goo_results.apply(lambda row: hour_convert(pd.to_datetime(row['_sent_time_stamp'], unit='s')), axis=1)
```

The date column works but the hour doesn't. I can't see why!

```
TypeError: ("'int' object is not callable", u'occurred at index 0')
```

Comment: You can just convert the entire column `df['hour'] = pd.to_datetime(df['_sent_time_stamp'], unit='s').dt.hour`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove `()` next `hour`:

```
def date_convert(time):
    return time.date()

def hour_convert(time):
    return time.hour #remove ()

df['date'] = df.apply(lambda row: date_convert(pd.to_datetime(row['_sent_time_stamp'], unit='s')), axis=1)
df['hour'] = df.apply(lambda row: hour_convert(pd.to_datetime(row['_sent_time_stamp'], unit='s')), axis=1)    
print df
   _sent_time_stamp  distance  duration  duration_in_traffic   Orig_lat  \
0        1456732800      1670       208                  343  51.441092   

         date  hour  
0  2016-02-29     8
```

But better and faster is use [`dt.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.date.html) and [`dt.hour`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.hour.html):

```
dat = pd.to_datetime(df['_sent_time_stamp'], unit='s')
df['date'] = dat.dt.date
df['hour'] = dat.dt.hour
print df
   _sent_time_stamp  distance  duration  duration_in_traffic   Orig_lat  \
0        1456732800      1670       208                  343  51.441092   

         date  hour  
0  2016-02-29     8
```

**Timings**:

```
In [20]: %timeit new(df1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 827 µs per loop

In [21]: %timeit lamb(df)
The slowest run took 4.40 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.13 ms per loop
```

Code:

```
df1 = df.copy()

def date_convert(time):
    return time.date()

def hour_convert(time):
    return time.hour


def lamb(df):    
    df['date'] = df.apply(lambda row: date_convert(pd.to_datetime(row['_sent_time_stamp'], unit='s')), axis=1)
    df['hour'] = df.apply(lambda row: hour_convert(pd.to_datetime(row['_sent_time_stamp'], unit='s')), axis=1)    
    return df

def new(df): 
    dat = pd.to_datetime(df['_sent_time_stamp'], unit='s')
    df['date'] = dat.dt.date
    df['hour'] = dat.dt.hour
    return df

print lamb(df)    
print new(df1)
```